# How to implement custom option for Vagrant without having invalid option warning?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile, getopt, rescue

I'm trying to implement new custom option for Vagrant as in the following `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
require 'getoptlong'

opts = GetoptLong.new(
  [ '--vm-name',        GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ],
)

vm_name        = ENV['VM_NAME'] || 'default'

begin
  opts.each do |opt, arg|
    case opt
      when '--vm-name';        vm_name        = arg
    end
  end
  rescue
# @fixme: An invalid option error happens here.
end

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.define vm_name
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vbox, override|
    override.vm.box = "ubuntu/wily64"
  end
end
```

Now, each time when I run any vagrant command it's showing the following warning, e.g.

```
vagrant destroy -f
```

> /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant: invalid option -- f

Another example:

```
$ vagrant --vm-name=foo up --no-provision
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant: unrecognized option `--no-provision'
Bringing machine 'foo' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> foo: Importing base box 'ubuntu/wily64'...
```

Is there any way that I can ignore such warning from happening in the above `rescue` section?

---

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3642331/55075) is similar, but it doesn't help much in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to do this in `Vagrantfile`. Vagrant parses options before loading `Vagrantfile`. The moment `Vagrantfile` is executed, Vagrant process is already in the `ensure` block after the exception that occurred because of the custom option in the command line. There is nothing one can do in `Vagrantfile` to recover from that.

Comment: I think it is possible, for the use case shown above - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I think it may be possible to avoid the error. Warning - I'm new to vagrant. However, this seems to do what you are looking for:

```
opts = GetoptLong.new(
  [ '--vm-name',        GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ],
  [ '--host-name',      GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ],
  [ '--provider',       GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ],
  [ '--no-provision',   GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ],
)
vm_name        = ENV['VM_NAME'] || 'default'
host_name      = ENV['HOST_NAME'] || 'localhost.localdomain'
```

If you can anticipate all the command line options you think will be passed to your vagrant invocation, you can add them to the getopts array and then just ignore the elements that you want to be handled by default vagrant processing.

Answer (score 0):

you could do in this fashion by just adding the option to your Vagrantfile as example:

```
opts = GetoptLong.new(
 [ '--ip', GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ],
 [ '-f', GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ]
)
```

and do not implement this option in the opt block as example:

```
opts.each do |opt, arg|
  case opt
    when '--ip'
        IP = arg
  end
end
```

then you can do `vagrant destroy -f` without of issue.
and for any other switch which is default to `vagrant` commands you would need to do same as example `❯ vagrant global-status --prune` would gave you exception:

```
Message: GetoptLong::InvalidOption: unrecognized option `--prune'
```

so to fix this you need to:

```
opts = GetoptLong.new(
 [ '--ip', GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ],
 [ '-f', GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ],
 [ '--prune', GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ]
)
```

and then you can execute `vagrant` command:

```
❯ vagrant global-status --prune
id       name   provider state  directory
--------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active Vagrant environments on this computer! Or,
you haven't destroyed and recreated Vagrant environments that were
started with an older version of Vagrant.
```